# Calculate with values of radio buttons in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

This is my first question here and I hope I do everything right. I have to write a program for my studies and learned python without prior knowledge thus I face some problems I usually solved alone but I am sitting on this issue for a week. Specifically, I want to calculate the sag for different overhead lines. For this I have developed a user interface with tkinter and with the help of radio buttons the different overhead line types are to be selected. I have assigned a value to each overhead line and now I want that when I press the button "draw", the sag is displayed depending on the selection. However, I don't know exactly how to make the calculation dependent on the value of the radio button.
Here is my code so far:

```
self.button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Zeichnen\n"+"Seitenansicht", fg_color=("gray75", "gray30"), command = self.calculate_sag)
self.button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=20)
```

...

```
    self.radio_var = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
    self.radio_button_1 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_right, text='Re 100', variable=self.radio_var, value=1)
    self.radio_button_1.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

    self.radio_button_2 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_right, text='Re 200', variable=self.radio_var, value=2)
    self.radio_button_2.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

    self.radio_button_3 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_right, text='Re 330', variable=self.radio_var, value=3)
    self.radio_button_3.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

    self.radio_button_4 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_right, text='Sicat S 1.0', variable=self.radio_var, value=4)
    self.radio_button_4.grid(row=4, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

    self.radio_button_5 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=self.frame_right, text='Sicat H 1.0', variable=self.radio_var, value=5)
    self.radio_button_5.grid(row=5, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")
```

I tried the following code for my calculations with the selection through the radio buttons:

```
 def calculate_sag(self):
    if (self.radio_var.get() == 1):
        sag_value = []
        nachspannlaenge = list(range(data[0]['nachspannlaenge']))
        for x in range(data[0]['nachspannlaenge']):
            sag = 5.50 - ((data[0]['gewicht_tragseil']/(8*data[0]['zugkraft_tragseil']))*(x*(data[0]['nachspannlaenge']-x)))
            sag_value.append(sag)
        plt.plot(nachspannlaenge, sag_value)
        plt.title('Durchhang für die (Oberleitungsbauart einfügen)')
        plt.xlabel('Nachspannlänge (m)')
        plt.ylabel('Fahrdrahthöhe (m)')
        plt.ylim() # changes the minimum value of the y axes
        plt.show()
    if (self.radio_var.get() == 2):
        sag_value = []
        nachspannlaenge = list(range(data[1]['nachspannlaenge']))
        for x in range(data[1]['nachspannlaenge']):
            sag = 5.50 - ((data[1]['gewicht_tragseil']/(8*data[1]['zugkraft_tragseil']))*(x*(data[1]['nachspannlaenge']-x)))
            sag_value.append(sag)
        plt.plot(nachspannlaenge, sag_value)
        plt.title('Durchhang für die (Oberleitungsbauart einfügen)')
        plt.xlabel('Nachspannlänge (m)')
        plt.ylabel('Fahrdrahthöhe (m)')
        plt.ylim() # changes the minimum value of the y axes
        plt.show()
```

However I receive the following error message:

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\customtkinter\widgets\ctk_radiobutton.py", line 279, in variable_callback
    if self.variable.get() == self.value:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 547, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""
```

For that I read that it has to do with my IntVar

The error does not happen if I have the calculation for only one overhead line at self.button_1 at command, like here:

```
self.button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Zeichnen\n"+"Seitenansicht", fg_color=("gray75", "gray30"), command = self.calculate_sag)
self.button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=20)
```

...

```
def sag_re_100(G=data[0]['gewicht_tragseil'], H=data[0]['zugkraft_tragseil'], l=data[0]['nachspannlaenge']):
    sag_value = []
    nachspannlänge = list(range(data[0]['nachspannlaenge']))
    for x in range(data[0]['nachspannlaenge']):
        sag = 5.50 - ((G/(8*H))*(x*(l-x)))
        sag_value.append(sag)
    plt.plot(nachspannlänge, sag_value)
    plt.title('Durchhang für die (Oberleitungsbauart einfügen)')
    plt.xlabel('Nachspannlänge (m)')
    plt.ylabel('Fahrdrahthöhe (m)')
    plt.ylim() # changes the minimum value of the y axes
    plt.show()
```

My entire program can be find here:
https://pastebin.com/an8Afa92

And this is the json file I store my information in:
https://pastebin.com/WrDwKKrW

How can I make the calculation depending on the value of the radio button?

Comment: I have this : https://pastebin.com/yXCsscXj which does some work depending of the radio button selected. However I can't see on which line you got this error, can you give more precision on this error ?

Comment: Thank you!
I added my entire program and it looks like this: https://pastebin.com/an8Afa92
I also added the entire error message.

Comment: Ok, now, when are you getting the error ? While trying to launch the program, or after clicking on a button ? (as I can't test your code with no data and not the complete requirements)

Comment: I get the error as soon as I launch the program. I also added my json file so you can fully replicate my program. My program is not finished yet, I have much to add and change but this is primarily by biggest issue. 

I guess that my function "calculate_sag" is wrong because when I tried to plot the sag for just one overhead line it worked just fine.

I hope that helps you. Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are overwritting self.button_1 on lines 74/77. You should try methods and algorythm on a simple python app, and then add them to a GUI program. As you are using specifics librairies, it is difficult to know what works, and what doens't work.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I corrected the numbering of the buttons.
I tried a simplier version with the code you had written in your first comment. It looks like this: https://pastebin.com/V41sKRgv

It works more or less like I want it but with that I am even more confused why my main code does not work...